# How can I sort an array returned from File.ReadAllLines on an alphabetical member?

Tags: c#

I am reading a .csv file and returning its lines in string array. One of the members is manufacturer, for which I have Toyota, Ford, etc.

I want to sort an array (Can be another collection) of the rows, by the value in manufacturer and alphabetical order.

So I'd have:

```
28437 Ford Fiesta
328   Honda Civic
34949 Toyota Yaris
```

and so forth...

What would be the best way to do this using C# and no database? I say no database because I could insert the csv into a table in a sql server database, and then query it and return the data. But this data is going into a html table built on the fly, which would make the database approach a little long winded.

Answer (score 2):

What version of .NET are you using? If you're using 3.5 - or can use C# 3.0 and [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) - then I'd definitely go with LINQ. First transform each line into some appropriate object, and then use OrderBy:

```
var cars = lines.Select(line => Car.ParseLine(line))
                .OrderBy(car => car.Manufacturer);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just have a bunch of strings in an Array, use

```
Array.Sort(myArray)
```

That will put the strings in "myArray" in alphabetical order (case sensitive).

If you want to to different comparisons (like case-insensitive for example), you can define an own ICcomparer or use Linq-Extensions, preferrably with a lambda expression like

```
        string [] sArray = new string[] { "fsdhj", "FA", "FX", "fxx", "Äbc" };
        sArray = sArray.OrderBy(s => s.ToLowerInvariant()).ToArray();
```

There's a whole bunch of other sorting methods, but these are the most basic. I could give you a more detailed answer to your problem, if I understood better what your input-object looks like. As long as it's just an array of strings, you should be fine with the above.

In response to the first two comments below I should also note that the invariant string-sorting method given above is not the best one for that particular job (see comments).

However it **does** illustrate the use of extension methods with lambda expressions, which come in very handy in situations where you don't have predefined IComparer-classes.

Comment: Or more simply: Array.Sort(sArray, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

Comment: Marc's solution is more correct as well as simpler. Case-insensitive sorting shouldn't be done by just converting to upper/lower case first. That has issues in some cultures (e.g. Turkish).

Comment: I'll have to take your word for the issues in Turkish or other languages. It works quite well in German though. Anyway, thanks for the comment. I should have used a better example.

Answer (score 1):

Without trying to second guess Jon, I believe he is suggesting that you would create a class Car ("some appropriate object") with the necessary properties, and the ability to populate a Car from a line:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Manufacturer {get;set;}
    public string Model {get;set;}

    public static Car ParseLine(string line)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(DELIMITER);
        return new Car
        {
            Id = int.Parse(parts[0]),
            Manufacturer = parts[1],
            Model = parts[2]
        };
    }
}
```

i.e. treating the lines as objects. Then with LINQ things become quite simple:

```
        var query = from line in lines
                    let car = Car.ParseLine(line)
                    orderby car.Manufacturer
                    select car;

        var arr = query.ToArray();
```

Note that you can do this without LINQ too, for example (using a `Car[]` array) - an in-place array sort:

```
        Array.Sort(arr, (x, y) => string.Compare(x.Manufacturer, y.Manufacturer));
```

or the same with `List<Car>`:

```
        list.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Manufacturer, y.Manufacturer));
```

Comment: Feel free to second guess me any time. You pretty much always either get it right or manage to explain something that I wasn't *actually* thinking, but should have been :)

Comment: You two should get paid by SO ;)

Comment: @David - now *there's* a thought <g>

Answer (score 1):

In Jon's post he is parsing the line into objects first, then sorting.  You could also just sort an IEnumerable list of strings based on part of the string.  Here is an example that is sorting the list on a substring (first 10 characters starting at position 6):

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>
    {
        "34949 Toyota Yaris",
        "328   Honda Civic",
        "28437 Ford Fiesta"
    };

var sortedLines = lines.OrderBy(line => line.Substring(6, 10));
// Or make it case insensitive
// var sortedLines = lines.OrderBy(line => line.Substring(6, 10), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

foreach (var line in sortedLines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```